# Find supremum and infimum of $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

If $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=\infty$, with $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable, then can I say by applying de l'Hopital that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f'(x)=-\infty$, and so $\sup{f'(x)}=+\infty$, $\inf{f'(x)}=-\infty$?
My doubt: how can I be sure that the limits of first derivative exist?

Comment: Sorry yes $x\to\pm\infty$

Comment: You cannot conclude that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=-\infty$. In fact, $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=+\infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes you're right! sorry sorry sorry there was a typo! I am referring to the first derivative...my doubt is if the limits of derivative exists necessarily!

Comment: okk...can you help me to find the solution?

Comment: You don't want L'Hopital's rule.  You want the mean value theorem.  Toward that end, just note that you can re-write the assumption as $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{|x|} = \infty$ because the difference, $f(0)/|x|$ goes to $0$.

Comment: The title still says infimum and supremum of $f(x)$. Please correct it.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's Rule cannot be applied, but you can use a very elementary argument to show that the supremum if $f'$ is $+\infty$ and infimum is $-\infty$. If $\sup f' <\infty$, say $f'(x) <M$ for all $x$ then $\frac {f(x)-f(0)} {|x|}<  M $ by Mean Value Theorem so $\lim \sup_{x \to \infty} \frac {f(x)} {|x|}\le M$ contradicting the hypothesis. Similarly, $\inf f'=-\infty$.